# Pass a sealed class as function argument android

Tags: android, kotlin, parameter-passing, sealed

I have a sealed class which represents the Retrofit Response of my API.

```
sealed class NetworkResponse<out T : Any, out U : Any> {
   
    data class Success<T : Any>(val body: T) : NetworkResponse<T, Nothing>()

    data class ApiError<U : Any>(val body: U, val code: Int) : NetworkResponse<Nothing, U>()

    data class NetworkError(val error: IOException) : NetworkResponse<Nothing, Nothing>()

    data class UnknownError(val error: Throwable?) : NetworkResponse<Nothing, Nothing>()
}
```

So now i want to create a function that handles all the errors of a failed request. I want to have only one argument that represents either ApiError or NetworkError or UnknownError

```
fun networkErrorHanlder(mError: <what_should_i_put_here??>) {
   // check if error is Api or Network or Unknown and do stuff...
}
```

What should be the type of the argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you care only about `ApiError`, `NetworkError` and `UnknownError`, which all derive from `NetworkResponse` but don't use the first generic type, you can specify that you don't care about it using `*` (Actually, depending on what you want to do with `mError`, you can replace `U` with `*` too - that is the case in the code below, but I introduced `U` just in case). In that case, you should accept a `NetworkReponse`:

```
fun <U : Any> networkErrorHanlder(mError: NetworkResponse<*, U>) {
    when(mError) {
        is NetworkResponse.ApiError ->
            print("Api stuff: ${mError.body}")
        is NetworkResponse.NetworkError ->
            print ("Network stuff: ${mError.error}")
        is NetworkResponse.UnknownError ->
            print("Unknown: ${mError.error}")
        else -> print("It must've been a Success...")
    }
}
```