# How can I extract the (successful) response body from a custom retrofit exception handler

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, exception, retrofit2

I followed [this guide](https://proandroiddev.com/create-retrofit-calladapter-for-coroutines-to-handle-response-as-states-c102440de37a) and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63238413/pass-a-sealed-class-as-function-argument-android) for handling network exceptions with Retrofit.  While they both are very useful, none of them explain how to extract the body of a successful request.  Here is a snippet of code that might better explain what I'm trying to accomplish:

The sealed class remains the same from both examples...

```
// exception handling:
sealed class NetworkResponse<out T : Any, out U : Any> {

    data class Success<T : Any>(val body: T) : NetworkResponse<T, Nothing>()

    data class ApiError<U : Any>(val body: U, val code: Int) : NetworkResponse<Nothing, U>()

    data class NetworkError(val error: IOException) : NetworkResponse<Nothing, Nothing>()

    data class UnknownError(val error: Throwable) : NetworkResponse<Nothing, Nothing>()
}
```

but extracting the body on a successful call is unclear to me.  Here is my attempt:

```
val oAuthRetrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(OAUTH_BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(Json.asConverterFactory(contentType))
    .build()
val salesforceOAuthAPI: SalesforceInterface =
    oAuthRetrofit.create(SalesforceInterface::class.java)

val oAuthAccessTokenResponse: NetworkResponse<OAuthAccessTokenResponse, Error> =
    salesforceOAuthAPI.getOAuthAccessToken(
        GRANT_TYPE,
        BuildConfig.SALESFORCE_CLIENT_ID,
        BuildConfig.SALESFORCE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        BuildConfig.SALESFORCE_USERNAME,
        BuildConfig.SALESFORCE_PASSWORD + BuildConfig.SALESFORCE_SECURITY_TOKEN
    )

val body = oAuthAccessTokenResponse.body  // Unresolved reference
// Use body()
```

How can I extract the body of a successful request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the medium post you have access to the [`Source Code`](https://github.com/mlegy/retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-call-adapter/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/melegy/retrofitcoroutines/MainActivity.kt) there you can check what you missing.

Answering your question

> How can I extract the body of a successful request?

You can simply do this :

```
val response1 = salesforceOAuthAPI.getWhatever()
when (response1) {
      is NetworkResponse.Success -> Log.d(TAG, "Success ${response1.body.name}")
      is NetworkResponse.ApiError -> Log.d(TAG, "ApiError ${response1.body.message}")
      is NetworkResponse.NetworkError -> Log.d(TAG, "NetworkError")
      is NetworkResponse.UnknownError -> Log.d(TAG, "UnknownError")
}
```

And in the `NetworkResponse.Success` you have the data you want, but since you are using a `sealed class` to detect the error and the data, you don't know what is inside that object until you do a `when`.

By the way, don't know if you followed all the post but you missing the

```
.addCallAdapterFactory(NetworkResponseAdapterFactory())
```

In the `Retrofit.Builder()` otherwise it won't do the *magic* to encapsulate everything to a `NetworkResponse`

Comment: I'm aware of the missing factory.  Is it really only by using `when`?  I'm pretty new to kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

Create new class for response model like BaseResponse

```
data class BaseResponse (
    val message: String? = "",
    val code: Int? = 0,
)
```

When request success pass the value of retrofit response to generic class you use

```
NetworkResponse.Success(response)
```

and post this value to livedata & observe this livedata on view.